# How to set a increase ASP.NET session timeout for my code C#?

Tags: asp.net

How do I increase the session timeout for my C# ASP.NET application?

Comment: Question is not clear to me, Do you want to increase your session expiration time ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done in the `<sessionState>` element of your `Web.config` file. Check MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
Session.Timeout = 4000;
```

It sets timeout in minutes.

or in `web.config` for all users as suggested by [David M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12212581#13198)